# Edit DiscordJS slash command permissions

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I am not a pro at NodeJS, but I just can't figure out how to edit permissions of a Discord slash command. I have seen https://discord.com/developers/docs/interactions/slash-commands#permissions but it has some lines of code that I cannot seem to get working. How do I use the PUT command or whatever?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a *guild* or a *global* command doesn't really matter. The permissions are set per guild. So you **always** need a `guildId`.

```js
const roleId = "...";
const guildId = "...";
const commandId = "...";
```

For discord.js v13:

```js
client.application.commands.permissions.set({
    guild: guildId,
    command: commandId,
    permissions: [
        {
            id: roleId,
            type: 1,
            permission: true
        }
    ]
});
```

For discord.js v12:

```js
client.api.applications(client.user.id).guilds(guildId).commands(commandId).permissions.put({
    data: {
        permissions: [
            {
                id: roleId,
                type: 1,
                permission: true
            }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: So I ran that command and it seemed to succeed. I awaited the set and it returned the id, permission, and type but it doesn't seem to be updated in Discord as I still have no access to the slash command. Any ideas?